# CSS text-align is not making the text center or right aligned

Tags: html, css, wordpress, accordion

In the following [link](https://rafiee.net/class-notes/), there is an Accordion, I want all Accordion's titles to be right aligned.
I used this CSS code:

```
.ekit-accordion-title {
    text-align: right;
}
```

However, the code is not working. What is the issue with code?

Comment: Please read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `.ekit-accordion-title` are `span` elements with `display: inline-block;`, they are as wide as their content requires. "Centering" within an element that is only as wide as its content to begin with, makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS code.

```
.elementskit-btn-link {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Or

```
.ekit-accordion-title {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: And use this CSS too. `.ekit-wid-con .ekit_accordion_icon_group { left: 0 !important; right: unset !important; margin-left: 30px !important; }` This CSS will make the arrows go to left.

Answer (score 1):

[image: See this working ss]To get the button text of the accordian elements to be right aligned, do this:

```
.maxbutton-1.maxbutton.maxbutton-account-page .mb-text{
    text-align: right;
}
```

To get the title of the accordian to align right, use this:

```
.ekit-wid-con .elementskit-accordion .elementskit-card-header>.elementskit-btn-link{
     justify-content: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this one change Icon alignment. I also want icons to be at left-end. This CSS doesn't make them aligned !

Comment: just change the padding value, in your code, the padding is `14px 30px`, change the value for horizontal padding according to your needs

Answer (score 1):

To align text to right side use this code on anchor element `.elementskit-btn-link`:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

If you wish to center it then this:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you add important to the CSS style

```css
#accordion {
  text-align: right
}

;
.ekit-accordion-title {
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work.